# Purpose of supports-screens android tag

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-screen-support

I am wondering if the `supports-screens` tag is needed in the manifest file when I don't plan to omit any screen sizes.  In other words, I want my app to run on as many screens as possible.  Sure, I can do something like this:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

But is it necessary?  Wouldn't Android just do this for me by default?

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to exclude anything, you don't need to add that.